# Better solution for adding rows to a table in angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am writing an angularJS web application. In my main page I have a table with one row of  (Drug, Period, Dose) labels. I would like to dynamically add rows to the table with one button (Add Drug), that has exactly the same content as the first

I was successfully able to do it. However my solution does not look like the ideal one.

in my HTML page shown below, I added the ng-repeat for row in each rows.

```
 <table class="table">
    <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
        <td>
            <label>{{row.drug}}
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>{{row.dose}}
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>{{row.period}}
            </label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In my controller, I had to specify in the addRow() function the name of every scope added, even though it was already given a string name when defined in $scope.rows. So I am repeating the same step.

```
 $scope.rows = [
                    {   'drug': "Drug",
                        'dose':'Dose',
                        'period': "Period",
                        }];

    $scope.addRow = function() {

        $scope.rows.push({'drug': "Drug", 'dose': "Dose", 'period': "Period});

    }
```

What is a better ideal solution?

Comment: Is the intent to be able to populate data using `<input>`. I see `<label>` and that usually implies `<input>`. If so solution is very simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use angular.copy();

```
$scope.rows = [
    {   
        'drug': "Drug",
        'dose':'Dose',
        'period': "Period",
    }
];

$scope.addRow = function() {

    $scope.rows.push(angular.copy($scope.rows[0]));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a copy of the first record and add it to the collection:

```
$scope.addRow = function() {
    $scope.rows.push(angular.copy($scope.rows[0]));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> In my controller, I had to specify in the addRow() function the name
>   of every scope added, even though it was already given a string name
>   when defined in $scope.rows. So I am repeating the same step.

I assume you are referring to the fact that you feel specifying the highlighted portions below feels like a repeat.

> $scope.rows.push({'**drug**': "Drug", '**dose**': "Dose",
>   '**period**': "Period});

I isn't necessarily bad. What you are doing is inserting a new object into the rows collection. And when you insert a new object you obviously want to specify the object attributes which is exactly what you are doing with

```
{'drug': "Drug", 'dose': "Dose", 'period': "Period}
```

---

You could ofcourse make it more explicit - like create a constructor for Drug, or insert an empty object and set the default values in the view to Drug, Dose and Period (which I assume are placeholders).